# Song tempo normalization

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, classification, normalization

I am looking for a function to normalize a song's tempo in order to classify it. All my features are between 0.0 and 1.0 and I am thinking of a way of putting the tempo between the same limits.

The problem is that tempos are usually grouped around similar values, most common of them being 70, 100, 120, 128 and 140. What function is best to apply in order to preserve these grouping around the new limits?

Comment: "All of my features are between 0.0 and 1.0..." - what does this mean?

Comment: It means that my features' values range between 0.0 and 1.0.

Comment: Okay. It seems a little strange to me to map tempo to a closed range, since there is no logical max value. What would you have as 1.0? You could use a cumulative distribution function if you have M and SD for your tempos. I don't really understand your question about preserving groupings either. If the bpm's in your data set cluster around 70, and your function maps 70 bpm to, say, 0.4, then... you will get a cluster around 0.4...? :)

Comment: By groupings I mean that values grouped around the main tempos I've listed above should be mapped to some closer values so that differences between groups should be higher while the in-group differences should be lower. There is no limit (both min and max values), but most songs map between some values. Usually 50-180. I didn't get your suggestion with M and SD.

Comment: Can you give some color as to what function this normalization serves for the purpose of classification? i.e. why is it better to normalize? this would help us help you...

Comment: Because most of my features have values between 0.0 and 1.0. If I don't normalize the tempo values, they will weight a lot more in the classification process.